# Both sidebar overlap each other

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If you first open the left sidebar and then click on the notification icon to open the right sidebar, this is what happens -

[image]

Comment: Would anyone mind terribly if this were retitled to "Sidebar Overflow"?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, we'll get it fixed soon :)

Comment: @CodyGray why not you go ahead and do that and we find out. :D

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi awesome. :) BTW, Thanks to the whole dev team for all the effort to give us this great app. :D

Comment: That's a lot of emails!

Comment: Haha. @GeorgeDuckett that's my secondary email ID. hardly check it. A cleanup is due. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is now fixed, it'll go out in a future update. Thanks!

Comment: Define future..

Comment: @CRUSADER "a representation of the result of an asynchronous computation". Oh. You probably don't mean that kind. It'll be fixed in version 0.1.5, which should be released in the next day or two. It relies on just fixing enough bugs that we think it warrants a release.

Comment: I can see this is resolved in 0.1.5 version which I got this morning.