# Difficult to Distinguish Messages in Inbox Sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, android-app

In the sidebar that shows your inbox messages, should the title and message text be the same gray color? It may just be my opinion, but I think it was easier to distinguish between messages when the title text was white and the message text was gray. I don't recall exactly in which update this changed but do know it was recent, possibly 0.1.34 or 0.1.35. Also, just to note, in the screenshot below I do have my brightness turned all the way up (just in case).

I'm on version 0.1.36

The post [Both sidebar overlap each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192303/222390) has a screenshot showing the difference in text color.

[image: Inbox Sidebar Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cosmetic change was done to help differentiate between read and unread inbox notifications. Unread inbox notifications now show up as both title and body white, where as read ones show as you displayed in the picture.

I'll gladly take any specific differentiation ideas in mind but I'm not going to revert it to the previous state because I think differentiating between read and unread is more important than title and body.

Comment: Ok, I see now when I saw your answer and that makes perfect sense. I think that is more important as well. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Going to mark this as by-design then :) If you have any suggestions for making it better let me know!